# PowerShell - Length condition with split return bad unexpected result

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We try to perform an extract from our Active Directory W12R2 with differents informations like :

- Comp Name
- Windows 10 Version.
- @IP
- Creation Date / Last login
- List item

Location (thank to our IP addresses)

Our network architecture looks like this:

- Agency 1: 10.126.1.0/24
- Agency 2 : 10.126.2.0/24
- ...

We've got execption with the head office whom is :

- 172.30.21.0/24
- 10.126.8.0/24
- 10.9.3.0/24

So, to retrieve the location of the station, I "split" the "." on the IP address of the computer and I add "FR" in front (with a 0 in front if there is only one digit).

The problem is, I can't handle the address exceptions.
Since the 172 network is the only one to have three digits at [0] and the 10.9.3.0 network one digit at [1], I wanted to filter with that. But when exporting in CSV, it is displayed FR21 and FR03 instead of FR08 and VPN.

I have no error message.

Thanks for your enlightenment

```
BEGIN {

}
PROCESS {

Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

$CSVPath = "\\MyPathToFolder\test"
$path = Split-Path -parent "$CSVPath\*.*" 
$pathispresent = Test-Path -Path $path
$dateofreport = Get-Date -Format ddmmyyyy
If ($pathispresent -eq $false) 
    {New-Item -type directory -Path $path}

$csvreportfile = $path + "\ALLADComputersW10_$dateofreport.csv" 

Get-ADComputer -filter {OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows 10*'} -property * | Select-Object `
        @{Label = "Nom machine";Expression = {$_.Name}},`
        @{Label = "Version Windows";Expression = {$_.operatingsystem}},`
        @{Label = "Adresse IP";Expression = {$_.ipv4Address}},`
        @{Label = "Code Agence";Expression = {
            if ($_.ipv4Address.split('.')[0].split(' ').length -eq 3) {
                "FR08"
                }
            elseif ($_.ipv4Address.split('.')[1].split(' ').length -eq 1) {
                "VPN"
                }
            else {
            "FR"+$_.ipv4Address.split('.')[2].split(' ').padLeft(2,'0')}
            }
          },`
        @{Label = "Date de création dans l'AD";Expression = {$_.Created}},`
        @{Label = "Date de connexion";Expression = {$_.lastLogonDate}},`
        @{Label = "Description";Expression = {$_.Description}} |`
        Export-Csv -Path $csvreportfile -Encoding Unicode -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
}

End {
write-Host "------"
Write-Host "Extraction terminée"
Write-Host "Fichier ALLADComputers_$dateofreport.csv créé"
write-Host "------"
Remove-Variable -name CSVPath
Remove-Variable -name path
Remove-Variable -name pathispresent
Remove-Variable -name dateofreport
Remove-Variable -name csvreportfile
```

Comment: Hi Akyrave_R, welcome to stack overflow. Its not easy for me to understand your question - can you provide clearer context at the beginning and a bit more background on what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: hi @alex_danielssen, thanks to Mclayton, my problem has benn solved. But, 
My problem was that I would handle the agency IP address exceptions from my 'Split'. Since I didn't know the 'StartWith' command, I made it difficult for myself. 
I wanted that in the "Code Agence" column to be displayed FR08 instead of FR21 (due to 172.30.21.X) and VPN instead of FR03 (due to 10.9.3.X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a bit of a meal of your special cases by twiddling the octect strings, and as a result they're not working quite how you'd hoped.

For example:

```bsh
PS> "172.30.21.0/24".Split(".")[0].Split(' ').Length
1 # your code expects '3' in order to hit the "FR08" filter
```

It's also going to be a bit brittle if you add new ranges in future - e.g. `10.8.3.0/24` that might trigger your "VPN" filter because they've only got one digit in the second octet.

Depending on how many exception cases you've got, it might be better to enumerate them specifically:

```bsh
{
    if ($_.ipv4Address -eq "172.30.21.0/24") {
        "FR08"
    }
    elseif ($_.ipv4Address -eq "10.9.3.0/24") {
        "VPN"
    }
    else {
        "FR" + $_.ipv4Address.split('.')[2].split(' ').padLeft(2,'0')}
    }
}
```

Or just compare the start of the string:

```bsh
{
    if ($_.ipv4Address.StartsWith("172.30.21.") {
        "FR08"
    }
    elseif ($_.ipv4Address.StartsWith("10.9.3.") {
        "VPN"
    }
    else {
        "FR" + $_.ipv4Address.split('.')[2].split(' ').padLeft(2,'0')}
    }
}
```

In both those examples it's lot clearer what you're trying to achieve, which will make the next person trying to maintain your script a lot happier :-).

And if you've got a lot of exceptions, maybe put them into a CSV file that maps the network range to a location code which you could read instead:

```
IPv4Address, OfficeCode
172.30.21.0/24, FR08
10.9.3.0/24, VPN
```